# How to wait in Rails without blocking the main thread?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails application that I am developing such that when users complete a payment, they will be redirected to a view in, say, controller A. The payment API that I am using also wants us to implement a callback URL, which is serviced by an action in controller B (this will trigger the payment status to be set to 'paid' in the database when the payment gateway sends a POST request to the said URL). What I want to know is, how do I write a while loop for the redirection action in controller A, to check whether the payment status has been set to 'paid' without blocking the main thread? When I test my app, the server console indicated that a POST request is initiated but the main thread is blocked by the while loop while redirecting so my app ended up in infinite loop. I tried using Ruby Threads but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: Try using background job.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need controller A to wait. Why? The payment processing may take from few seconds to a few hours. Do you expect the user to sit and watch the "loading page" spinner?

Instead, you advance the process in the payment gateway callback controller (set status to "paid", email the user and start delivering the goods).

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a running Rails app as a giant while loop: wait for requests, receive a request, process the requests, wait for next request. It sounds like your payment processor is designed to integrate nicely with this architecture by providing you the ability to specify the callback URL (aka your app exposing a webhook) in controller B. If you block that loop your app will stop responding to new requests.

I understand your question is about how to update the user. Once the user has completed the payment, it's standard to redirect them to a page accessed by a GET request so that refreshing the browser doesn't resubmit their payment (probably a POST). Let's imagine that's a "show order" action which includes the status of payment as either "pending" or "processed". When the user first sees the page it would show status: pending. Later, after the payment processor hits the callback in controller B, if the user visits the same page or refreshes it in their browser, it should show status: processed.

If you want the page to update on its own, you would generally do that with polling in javascript. You could expose a JSON response from the same action (or a new action that just returns the order payment status), then build a loop running in javascript in the browser that hits that action every few seconds to see if the status has changed, then end when it has. Consider using an exponential rolloff to update the status quickly in the common case where it happens moments later, but to avoid too many requests to your server if it takes minutes or hours.